# When building a native quarkus image, how should I (re-)structure my code to enable runtime class initialization?

Tags: java, quarkus, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I'm building a native image with quarkus and the graal analysis fails with the error:

```java
Error: No instances of sun.security.provider.NativePRNG are allowed in the image heap as this class should be initialized at image runtime. Object has been initialized without the native-image initialization instrumentation and the stack trace can't be tracked.
Detailed message:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
Trace: Object was reached by                                                                                                      
        reading field java.security.SecureRandom.secureRandomSpi of                                                               
                constant java.security.SecureRandom@472a6481 reached by                                                                                                                                                                                              
        scanning method com.nimbusds.oauth2.sdk.id.Identifier.<init>(Identifier.java:112)                                                                                                                                                                            
Call path from entry point to com.nimbusds.oauth2.sdk.id.Identifier.<init>(int):                                                                                                                                                                                     
        at com.nimbusds.oauth2.sdk.id.Identifier.<init>(Identifier.java:105)                                                                                                                                                                                         
        at com.nimbusds.oauth2.sdk.token.Token.<init>(Token.java:62)                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        at com.nimbusds.oauth2.sdk.token.AccessToken.<init>(AccessToken.java:121)                                                                                                                                                                                    
        at com.nimbusds.oauth2.sdk.token.BearerAccessToken.<init>(BearerAccessToken.java:114)                                                                                                                                                                        
        at ff.service.identity.application.OAuthAccessTokenProvider.generateAccessToken(OAuthAccessTokenProvider.java:78)                                                                                                                                            
        at ff.service.identity.application.OAuthAccessTokenProvider.completeAccessTokenGeneration(OAuthAccessTokenProvider.java:62)                                                                                                                                  
        at ff.service.identity.application.OAuthAccessTokenProvider_ClientProxy.completeAccessTokenGeneration(OAuthAccessTokenProvider_ClientProxy.zig:198)                                                                                                          
        at ff.service.identity.application.OAuthService.validateSignedChallenge(OAuthService.java:187)                                                                                                                                                               
        at ff.service.identity.application.OAuthService_Subclass.validateSignedChallenge$$superaccessor1(OAuthService_Subclass.zig:258)                                                                                                                              
        at ff.service.identity.application.OAuthService_Subclass$$function$$1.apply(OAuthService_Subclass$$function$$1.zig:41)                                                                                                                                       
        at sun.security.ec.XECParameters$1.get(XECParameters.java:183)                                                            
        at com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.SystemPropertiesSupport.initializeLazyValue(SystemPropertiesSupport.java:190)                                                                                                                                                     
        at com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.SystemPropertiesSupport.getProperty(SystemPropertiesSupport.java:143)                                                                                                                                                             
        at com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.Target_java_lang_System.getProperty(JavaLangSubstitutions.java:345)                                                                                                                                                               
        at com.oracle.svm.jni.JNIJavaCallWrappers.jniInvoke_ARRAY:Ljava_lang_System_2_0002egetProperty_00028Ljava_lang_String_2_00029Ljava_lang_String_2(generated:0)
```

It correctly and logically states that the class for the random number generator provider should be initialised at runtime. However, unlike in the [docs](https://quarkus.io/guides/writing-native-applications-tips#delaying-class-initialization), no call path is given because the:

> Object has been initialized without the native-image initialization instrumentation and the stack trace can't be tracked

I don't know how to go about restructuring my code to support this, and I'm not doing anything really exotic, as far as I can tell. To prepare this question, I brutally moved the code together involving classes from `com.nimbusds`, and it now resides in `OAuthService` and `OAuthAccessTokenProvider`. `OAuthService` is only used by my `OAuthResouce`, and even after making these two services `@RequestScoped` to enforce lazy initialization, the error message remains unchanged.

When I add `--initialize-at-run-time=ff.service.identity.application.OAuthService`, I actually receive less information about the observed problem.

```java
Error: Classes that should be initialized at run time got initialized during image building:
 ff.service.identity.application.OAuthService the class was requested to be initialized at run time (from the command line). ff.service.identity.application.OAuthService has been initialized without the native-image initialization instrumentation and the stack trace can't be tracked. Try avoiding to initialize the class that caused initialization of ff.service.identity.application.OAuthService

com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError$UserException: Classes that should be initialized at run time got initialized during image building:
 ff.service.identity.application.OAuthService the class was requested to be initialized at run time (from the command line). ff.service.identity.application.OAuthService has been initialized without the native-image initialization instrumentation and the stack trace can't be tracked. Try avoiding to initialize the class that caused initialization of ff.service.identity.application.OAuthService

        at com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError.abort(UserError.java:68)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.classinitialization.ConfigurableClassInitialization.checkDelayedInitialization(ConfigurableClassInitialization.java:518)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.classinitialization.ClassInitializationFeature.duringAnalysis(ClassInitializationFeature.java:187)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.lambda$runPointsToAnalysis$8(NativeImageGenerator.java:720)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.FeatureHandler.forEachFeature(FeatureHandler.java:70)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.runPointsToAnalysis(NativeImageGenerator.java:720)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.doRun(NativeImageGenerator.java:538)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.lambda$run$0(NativeImageGenerator.java:451)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1407)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:177)
```

I'm supposted to avoid initializing these classes, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong or what other possibilities exist. What have I overseen?

**EDIT:** I am building with Quarkus 1.6.1.Final, using GraalVM Version 20.1.0 (Java Version 11.0.7).

A solution involving the flag `--rerun-class-initialization-at-runtime` is actually deprecated since GraalVM 19.0.0 (I can't find a link):

> Warning: Using a deprecated option --rerun-class-initialization-at-runtime. Currently there is no replacement for this option. Try using --initialize-at-run-time or use the non-API option -H:ClassInitialization directly.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you need to use `rerun-class-initialization-at-runtime= com.nimbusds.oauth2.sdk.id.Identifier`